# MySQL Database Clarification

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am new to Database Design and I really need some help figuring this one out.

I have a table called Processes, this table holds all the names of the job processes. I then have a table called TrainingProcesses. This table simply has the names Process1, Process2, Process3 and so on until Process30.

Each employee can train up to 30 processes. So for an employees first process he is learning, I need to be able to select a process ID, assign that process ID to Process1 in his profile. Process1 is not anything specific, it's just going to be whatever job process they assign to him.

Can you tell me how I would link all this together?

- `EmployeeInformationTable`

  - `Id``
  - `FirstName"
  - `LastName`
- `ProcessesTable`

  - `Id`
  - `Appm`
  - `Route H`
  - `RouteJ`
- `TrainingProcessesTable`

  - `Process1`
  - `Process2`
  - `Process3`
  - `EmployeeInformationTable Id`
  - `ProcessTable Id`

Would it be done like above in simple terms?

Comment: SO expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: In the bottom half of the post I posted how I am thinking of doing it, but I don't know if that's going to work or not.

Comment: This is not a "Do my homework for me" website :) Try and figure this one on your own and comeback once you've made a little progress... People will be more enclined to help.

Comment: I posted it on the bottom of the post how I am thinking of doing it and asked for verification if that was correct?

Comment: That's just a list of tables and columns, not how everything is related.

Comment: In general, you should avoid columns like `Process1`, `Process2`, etc. If you need a 1-to-many relationship, use a table with a row for each item.

Comment: Thank you for the help that's all I needed to know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure as it is works, and achieves your desired goals.  So could it be done like the above simple terms?  Yes.

You may also want to consider removing the "process1-30" columns from the TrainingProcessTable, and just limiting the max number of processes an employee can train up to inside of the logic of your application instead of the database.  The benefit for this would be that if you needed to increase the number of processes an employee can train up to you will not have to alter your database schema.

(EmployeeInformationTable) "Id" "FirstName" "LastName"

(ProcessesTable) "Id" "Appm" "Route H" "RouteJ"

(TrainingProcessesTable) "EmployeeInformationTable Id" "ProcessTable Id"

Answer (score 0):

You do *not* want to store the processes as separate columns.  This just causes headaches when you want to do something like "add a new process after all the other ones".

- `EmployeeInformationTableId`
- `ProcessTableId`

And you probably want more information as well:

- Date/time completed
- Completion metric (time, quality)
- Sequential number
- etc.

How do you restrict the length to 30 per employee?  Unfortunately, this is a bit tricky:

1. One method is just to do it in the application layer (count the number of existing rows before adding a new one).
2. A second method is to wrap all DML operations in stored procedures, and write the logic there.
3. A third method is to use triggers to prevent the operation.

In practice (1) is easiest; (2) is often what I do anyway, and (3) is perhaps the safest, so the database maintains the integrity.